# In Windows 7, can I create a Symlink or Junction for winsxs or installer folders

Tags: windows-7, ssd, mklink

I have an SSD as my C:\ drive, and it's only 128 Gig.

I'm noticing that the C:\Windows subfolders "winsxs" and "Installer"--both of which I've read numerous places that one should *never* delete unless they want a nightmare--are taking the biggest chunk of space.

So, can I create a Junction using the mklink command after moving the data to one of my spindle drives with more space?
Thanks,
--Jim

Comment: I keep reading that this can't be done because those are "already" symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for Installer. You can use this tool:

http://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php

[image]

> JunctionMaster is a small and simple shell extension that will allow you to MOVE and 
>   LINK a folder in one easy step. It focuses on MOVING the folder, then
>   replacing the original folder with a hard link (junction) to the new
>   location. Windows (and the user) can reference the files at the same
>   location as before, but the actual storage of them is on the other
>   drive. It is handy for new hard drives, and also in the case of SSDs
>   where you may wish to redirect some folders with lots of RW activity
>   to a conventional HDD.
>
> For instance, if you bought a new hard drive you might wish to move
>   some large folders without having to change their paths? For instance,
>   having it store the stuff in c:\movies, but not having the path of
>   c:\movies change. This is what JunctionMaster will do. It would move
>   the files to f:\movies, but c:\movies still accesses them just the
>   same (with no perceptible difference at all in the shell until Windows
>   7, where it now shows a link overlay on the folder icon). You must be
>   CAREFUL though as deleting the files from either location will delete
>   them in both (since only one real copy exists).

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't use that particular tool, but I used the native mklink and did it to the Installer folder.   I haven't tried winsxs yet, but from what I understand winsxs probably would benefit my system more from being on the SSD drive, so I'll keep it there.  I freed up more space by moving a bunch of larger program's help files and some other huge but rarely-used files.  I now have 40 Gig free and no longer feel the need to get a 256 Gig ssd, so it saved me some cash.

Comment: @James could you please tell the exact command you used for the symlink ? (put it into the edit of your question if you like).

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/707767/how-can-i-to-free-up-drive-space-from-the-windows-installer-folder-without-killi