# Not enough disk space to upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: disk-space, windows-10-upgrade

I am on Windows 7 and wish to upgrade to Windows 10,
but I do not have enough disk space for the upgrade.
I think that I need to upgrade to Windows 10 through Windows 7,
rather than start from a reformatted hard disk.

The biggest chunk of disk space is taken up by the
`winsxs` folder (some files are 6 years old), but the proper way isn't working. I ran Disk Cleanup as an admin, and the selection to clean up Windows Update files still doesn't appear:

I also tried `DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /SpSuperseded` and got:

> Service Pack Cleanup can't proceed: No service pack backup files were found.
>   The operation completed successfully.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

[EDIT] Trying to work out Disk Cleanup still. I have KB2852386 installed:

```
C:\Users\Zeno>wmic qfe | find "KB2852386"
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2852386     WIN7SSD  Update
      KB2852386               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  12/1/2013
```

Why is "Windows Update Cleanup" not showing up like it does [here](https://superuser.com/a/875950/110814)?

Comment: Your screenshot clearly show, the command you are trying to run, has already been performed.  Your installation cannot superseed the service pack, because you have already performed the cleanup routine, in other words there is nothing to superseed.

Comment: @Ramhound What can I do to clean up these 14GB of backups/files? C drive is down to 100MB free and this is the biggest section

Comment: You can manually remove those files.  The catch if you do that is if your installation needs to be repaired you won't be able to do so.  Lots of information on how to do that exists I won't help you break your installation though.

Comment: Just because the files are old, doesn’t mean they aren’t used anymore. The whole point of the Winsxs folder is to have multiple versions of a file available at the same time. That’s why it appears big. **To properly analyze it, you need a hardlink-aware tool.**

Comment: @DanielB What can I use for that? I have 2GB free and I'm simply trying to free up space to upgrade to Win10 then reformat.

Comment: Windows 10 1511 can be activated directly using a Windows 7+ key/embedded license.

Comment: @DanielB Right yes, I have that. But there is not enough disk space for this to proceed thus this whole topic where winsxs is the biggest folder taking up space preventing the upgrade.

Comment: What I’m saying is that you don’t need to upgrade. You just need a bootable Windows 10 USB drive and you’re good to go. Surely you have some other means to obtain one. Because there’s no proper way to fix this.

Comment: @DanielB Oh I can do that easily, but thought that wouldn't work? "There’s no way to enter a Windows 7 or 8.1 key into the Windows 10 installer, nor is there some sort of web form that will give you a Windows 10 key if you provide your Windows 7 or 8.1 key. Sorry — you’ll have to upgrade to Windows 10 before you can perform a clean install." http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33500/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-zeno).

Comment: @DanielB: Why don't you post this (with details) as an answer - yours is the best answer. I edited the post to better reflect the above discussion.

Answer (score 5):

There’s an easier way to achieve your goal: Obtain a Windows 10 1511 installation medium somewhere and perform a clean installation directly.

Since Windows 10’s November Update (called 1511), it is possible to activate directly using a Windows 7+ Product Key (or Windows 8+ Embedded License). The result is the same: You get a “Digital Entitlement” type activation that is valid for your PC. That means it’ll be automatically picked up whenever you reinstall Windows 10 on the same PC. Details on this procedure, including which types of Product Keys are not eligible for this method, are available [at Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10).

Apparently, you can enter the “old” Product Key even during Setup, but you could also skip entering the Key there. I used this method once. I skipped entering the Key during Setup.

Prior to the 1511 version you could not activate directly using a non-Windows-10 Product Key, making the whole “upgrade and then clean install” procedure necessary. Because the 1511 update is relatively new, information in the previous state of affairs is more dominant in the Internet.

I also recommend using partition that’s at least 60 GiB for installing Windows.

Comment: "Somewhere" would be [the official download page...](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

Comment: I meant somewhere as in some PC, because he might not have enough space to create it himself.

Comment: Obligatory [Microsoft Testbench](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) link to the current Windows 10 .ISO

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've already cleaned the RTM files or installed Windows 7 with a DVD which already has the Sp1 included. In both cases you can't shrink WinSxS with this Sp clean command any longer.

But you can  [cleanup WinSxS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/08/breaking-news-reduce-the-size-of-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-with-a-new-update-for-windows-7-sp1-clients.aspx) by removing old and replaced Updates after [installing Update KB2852386](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386/en-us) and running disk cleanup again.

If the WindowsUpdate option doesn't show up, Windows can't remove any updates.

If you have low free storage to upgrade, you need to use a [2 USB drives](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Lots-of-Windows-10-Stick-PCs-PST-tips-Zombie-Libraries-and-more#time=0m36s). Install the Windows 10 Media to the 1 USB stick and leave the second empty. During the Windows 10 setup, that you started from USB drive 1, Windows setup will tell that you don't have enough free space and will allow to use the 2nd (empty) USB drive for storing temporary files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have KB2852386 installed already.

Comment: 1 note. if you can't see the entry, even after installing the update it means, that there are no files which can be cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

The big green file, is it a pagefile? Change the pagefile size, maybe even consider temporarily disabling pagefile whatsoever. The same goes for hiberfil.sys (disable hibernation using `powercfg -h off`). You need around 20GB of free space before upgrading - how far are you from reaching the goal?

I have struggled with HDD space issues and the fix I've found is involving an NTFS junction to the files - I have done that with Visual Studio Program data to redirect the gigabytes off from my SSD to a HDD. I've used `junction` utility from SysInternals. While I would advise **against** moving `WinSxS` through a junction point to another (removable) drive, you might find it handy to move non-system critical files to a different drive this way. You will want to use a `junction` for folders that must be accessed at the specific path (ex. C:\Program Files) - even though the actual data will reside on a different drive. While I can't testify for accuracy of [this article](http://aspoc.net/archives/2007/12/05/how-to-move-the-winsxs-directory-in-vista/) it might give you some overview on how would you actually move the `WinSxS` directory, even temporarily.

Comment: Whoever downvotes, any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I use Auslogics DiskDefrag for defragmenting (duh), but newer versions have options to remove temp files, update files, and the likes, before performing the defrag. It's free, does a better job that Disk Cleanup at removing update files, and never gave a problem, you might want to try it out. Wise Care 365 also does a good job at removing backup update files.

Another tool you can try is CCleaner which may help you remove other junk files from your computer, every bit counts!

In case you're using Google Chrome, it has a tendency to accumulate huge amount of cache files over time, try clearing the cache to save some space.

One more thing you can do is delete hiberfile.sys (temporarily for update purpose) by running the following command as administrator `powercfg.exe -h off`, will save you a few GBs. Once you're done upgrading, you can re-enable hibernation by replacing `off` with `on`

Answer (score -2):

Lets get this straight, you are upgrading to Windows 10. The upgrade is free and you will need to do an upgrade to use your upgrade key. You will not be able to freely install windows 10 without purchasing a windows 10 key.
Once you upgrade to windows 10, that windows 10 key is then registered to your hardware (motherboard). After you upgrade and activate, you can then do a clean install and hit skip when it asks for your key.

As far as getting it installed, move as much data off that you can. Use a program such as spacesniffer to find where and what is taking up space.

Comment: "You will not be able to freely install windows 10 without purchasing a windows 10 key." - This isn't correct.

Comment: If you read the one line correct. You have to upgrade first so it can associate the key to the hardware unless. 

Is this not correct?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "upgrade key" for Windows 10 when you accept the free upgrade, there is no key given, in the end all users who accept the free upgrade end up using the same version specific generic Windows 10 key. This generic key cannot be used to install Windows 10.  *Furthermore with the release of Version 1511 you can upgrade with the key from an eligible version of Windows directly.*

Comment: @Ramhound I am glad the fixed in in version 1511! The upgrade "key" i am talking about is the one built in associate.