# DSIM.exe wont remove files

Tags: windows-7, windows, dism

I need some help cleaning up a winsxs folder that is about 15GB in widows7.
I went to [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/), hoping that i could use the dsim command to reduce the size of winsxs. instead I get error 87, "remove option not recognized in this context" I went to MS technet, to look for support, but the support was something like, make sure you typed the command properly. I have typed the commands properly, and spacing is not the issue.

I have these disabled features, I would like to remove completely:
How do I do it?
[image]

Comment: Please provide the precise syntax you used.  You have all available updates for Windows 7 installed.  The article in question only applies to Windows 7 if the required update is installed.  If you want our help, this information will help us, understand what is going on precisely with your system.  *The lack of this information makes it unanswerable *

Comment: A 15 GiB WinSxS folder is quite normal. If you want Windows to use less space, you should upgrade to newer versions.

Comment: because windows is taking op 15+GB in Winsxs, I cant upgrade. I dont have room.

Comment: [No need to do an in-place upgrade. ;)](http://superuser.com/q/994096/219095)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Features on Demand](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/11/20/features-on-demand-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) is a Windows 8 only feature (parameter is still there in `Windows 10`, but the feature only works for Server 2016). So the `/Remove` parameter in the command `DISM.exe /Online /Disable-Feature /featurename:NAME /Remove` is detect as unknown in Windows 7.

So update to Windows 8.1 to get this feature.

The only way to reduce the size of the WinSxS in Windows 7 is to [install this update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386) and run Disk Cleanup and select "Windows Update Cleanup":

[image]

[image]

After a reboot the old updates are removed and WinSxS will be cleaned up.

[image]

This can reduce the WinSxS a lot.

Comment: I’m trying it, it didn't really say there would be substantial space saving. 
i'm kinda wondering if i delete the Winsxs folder entirely, if my PC will still function. Thanks for the explanation, I might have read something similar, but I think I got it when you explained it. Thanks for that.
it turns out I also had old restore points that were still hanging around, despite having turned off system restore.

Comment: when I used this on family PCs it cleaned several GBs because of a lot of old IE updates