# COMCTL32.dll Version

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, dll

One of the Windows Updates of 2015 has updated the file version of 5.82.7601.18837 on this Home Premium rig, the Product Version is 6.1.7601.18837. 
According to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/3059317) the last good versions for Win 7 are 6.1.7601.xxxxx, but note the file size of the most recent available at [Originaldll](http://originaldll.com/download/3177.7z) are substantially larger.
Looking at the table in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349(v=vs.85).aspx) both PACKVERSIONs 5.82 and 6.1 are okay for Windows 7, but what determines the criteria for the different versions?
One could risk just copying the newer file in at boot, but without the manifests being updated accordingly something could well break. Haven't been able to track down a msu install for this file at all.
Can anyone suggest to what we might be missing in the larger, newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5.82 is the version for old legacy applications. The newer version includes the [UXTheme support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) that Windows supports since Windows XP.

Comment: Interesting. "Windows ships with both version 5 and version 6." Guessing that depends on whether it is Home Premium or Professional etc.Apparently then with VS10 Pro I cannot use it?

Comment: no all Windows version have both files

Comment: Well then there is a problem here as only 5.82 is in the `system32` and `sysWOW64` folders.

Comment: this is fine. This is the DLL for legacy tools so they load this old DLL from system32. Applications with a manifest file (see the link) load the new version 6 DLL from WinSxS to get UxTheme support

Comment: Oh right, as a matter of fact there are 306 of the dang things in WinSxS- thanks.

Comment: clean them up a bit: http://superuser.com/a/875950/174557